# Bxslider Pager Issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, pager, bxslider

Using [bxslider](/questions/tagged/bxslider), I moved my [pager](/questions/tagged/pager) inside of my slideshow and it's doing some funky things in [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox). I tested it in IE and there were no problems. Crazy, right?

I found a solution on here that suggested using "clear:both;" on the bxslider container. This did not fix the problem. Can anyone assist me?

Check out the issue  [here](http://www.coppermstudio.com/indexNEW.html) using Firefox and watch the pager as the slider automatically goes through the images.

Comment: Looks fine in ff to me.

Comment: @Chad it appears to only happen when I preview (F12) it out of Dreamweaver. I'm retarded. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Yea, bx is pretty solid. It's by far my favorite I've used.